# How to give API response with futures in Scala (Akka-Http and Slick)

Tags: scala, future, akka-http

i'm working on an api for library management in Scala, using Slick and Akka-Http. I defined an endpoint, that takes id: Int, and passes it to the function, that takes integer and returns `Future[Option[Book]]`:

```scala
      def getBook(id: Int) = {
       db.run(bookByIdQuery(id).take(1).result.headOption).
          map(result => result.map(Book.tupled))}
```

I'd like to use it to give a response, something like:

```scala
    lazy val route =  pathPrefix("books") {path(IntNumber) { id => complete(getBook(id)}}
```

The above, for the sake of simplicity, assumes that `Book` is marshallable, and the function always gives correct answer.

My main problem, is how to get the value from this future? So far i tried:

1. Using `Await.result` in the function body. It works, but i was told it is a bad practice - as i understand, we don't introduce parallel execution just to freeze one thread and make it wait for the other.
2. I got an advice to use callbacks like `onComplete` or `foreach` - but their return type is Unit, so, something like:

```scala
lazy val route =  pathPrefix("books") {path(IntNumber) { id => getBook(id).foreach{i => complete(i)} }}
```

doesn't work, because route requires return type of Route, not Unit.

So, what's the most effective way of turning `Future[Book]` into `Book` and passing it in response?

Comment: You can `map` the values in `Future` like `complete(getBook(id).map(???))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives` it has methods to work with `Future` results.

```scala
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.FutureDirectives._

val route =
  pathPrefix("books") {
    path(IntNumber) { id =>
       onComplete(getBook(id)) {
         case Success(book) => complete(book)
         case Failure(ex)   => complete(InternalServerError, s"An error occurred: ${ex.getMessage}")
       }
    }
  }
```

Here you can find more examples: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/future-directives/onComplete.html

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now. If i may have another question - if i request the non-existent book (the id is not in db), it never reaches the Failure part - i just get the generic "There was an internal server error." - do you know, what can be the cause?

Comment: I can guess that you faced an unhandled exception that was caught by the default akka http error handler. But I'm not sure about the source of error that throws not inside of your Future. You can try to trace it with other directive `handleExceptions(yourCustomErrorHandler)`  - https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/execution-directives/handleExceptions.html